# Laptop battery voltage reading varies wildly

Tags: batteries, voltage-regulator, integrated-circuit

My laptop has that annoying tendency to suddenly drop to zero from about 50%, even through I can force it to keep running at 0%.

I was investigating the issue and the voltage readings reported by the device are unexpected for a lithium battery (a ~42Wh 3 cell ~11.5V battery).

[image]

Notice the fluctuation of the voltage whenever the device is idling, but it settles at lower values when the device is loaded (at about t=800s)

What is, from an electronics perspective, the reason behind this? Notice that the fluctuations are mostly periodic so it doesn't seem random to me.

Comment: I wonder why this got downvoted. Please provide useful feedback if something isn't right.

Answer (score 2):

When idle, your laptop is probably still running background tasks that require the CPU to do *something*, even if that something isn't very much. In order to save power, the CPU goes into a low-power "sleep" mode (note that this is not the same as putting the laptop in sleep mode) and periodically "wakes up" to do tasks it can't do in sleep mode. This causes short power usage spikes that are usually going to be periodic, with the exact period depending on factors like the design of the CPU, what specific tasks need to be done, and so forth. This is not a quirk of your laptop; all modern processors designed for use in battery-powered devices do this.

The increased power usage when "awake" corresponds to lower battery voltage due to the battery's internal resistance.

This is all a long-winded way of saying that the battery voltage profile you see is entirely normal and expected. If your estimated capacity is suddenly dropping from 50% to 0%, that indicates a problem with your battery--the battery is old and worn enough that it no longer has the designed capacity, but the laptop's charge controller doesn't realize that. There may be ways to recalibrate the charge controller, but really, you should look into replacing the battery.

Comment: The battery is barely a year old and not much charge cycles were put into it. It isn't possible that something else is not working properly?

Comment: @td211 The battery being old is a likely reason, but not the only reason the charge controller can get miscalibrated. It's possible the battery is still fine and there's something else wrong.

Comment: Another note: I haven't seen these somewhat high voltage fluctuations on another laptop that doesn't have this issue, the voltage is almost constant there. (both at idle and same OS)

Comment: @td211 An old or faulty battery would cause the fluctuations to be worse. Maybe you just got a dud battery?

Comment: (the OS has little to do with the magnitude of the power spikes, by the way; that's largely controlled at a lower level, by BIOS settings and the choice of what specific CPU is being used.)

Comment: I guess this device has another issue, since this battery was a replacement for the previous one that exhibited this same behavior. I'm either too unlucky to keep getting duds or something else mysterious is at play.

Comment: @td211 Could be a problem with the device then. Or could it be that both batteries were knockoffs that might have lower capacity than claimed?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/150345/discussion-between-td211-and-hearth).

Answer (score 0):

It is the voltage drop I*R - when there is a power draw the voltage will drop a bit at the point you are measuring.  If you could measure directly at the cells it would be steady at the higher voltage.

Comment: Are you allowing for the cells deteriorating internal resistance as they age?

Comment: The weird thing about this is that the voltage drop is quite large even though the CPU is barely loaded. It is about 0.5-1V of drop for a somewhat small current. Thus I'm confused.

Comment: @td211 The current may spike much higher than you'd think for very short periods (on the order of a microsecond or two). The average current still works out pretty low. Older batteries also have worse internal resistance as Transistor notes.